# Using re.sub to manipulate pandas df column with stored constraints **V HELPFUL**

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

This problem took me a while to figure out, and there were only bits a pieces on stack overflow so I thought I'd share in case anyone is running into this problem.

Goal:

- 1- Change string in entire PD DF Column based on dictionary stored constraints
- 2- Avoid replacing substrings that take place within other words
- 3- Do so on the entire pandas df column without looping through O(n)

Example Input.

Expected answer

- *'107 AVELRIGHT AV'* -> **'107 AVELRIGHT Avenue**
- *1084 LAMONTDRO LA'* -> **1084 LAMONTDRO Lane**

Without Getting

- *'107 AVELRIGHT AV'* -> **'107 AvenueELRIGHT Avenue**
- *1084 LAMONTDRO LA'* -> **1084 LaneMONTDriveO Lane**

Comment: Can you provide some of your input data ?

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug yea sure! Is there a way I can upload a csv file on here?

Comment: yes you can copy output of `df.head(5)` and put that in code format.

Comment: Gotcha will do it now! @k33da_lets_debug

Comment: Just posted! @k33da_lets_debug

Answer (score 0):

```
#here is the dictionary constraint
add_map = dict([
    ("AV", "Avenue"),
    ("BV", "Boulevard"),
    ("BP", "Bypass"), 
    ("BY", "Bypass"),
    ("CL", "Circle"),
    ("DR", "Drive"),
    ("LA", "Lane"),
    ("PY", "Parkway"),
    ("RD", "Road"),
    ("ST", "Street"),
    ("WY", "Way"),
    ("TR", "Trail"),
    
      
])
```

You can have as many constraints as you'd like. O(j) (where j = # dict constraints) does not get written into pandas df with solution below. Look for **~~~ below.

```
data_909['Address_new'] = data_909['Address'] #make a new df column 
#print(data_909['Address_new']) #print it!

obj = data_909['Address'].copy() #make a copy cuz why not. I just kept this here cuz I'm lazy.
for k,v in add_map.items(): #iterate through the dictionary constraints 
    rule1 = (r"(\b)(%s)(\b)" % k) **solves problem 2, lookup \b regex**
    rule2 = (lambda m: add_map.get(m.group(), m.group())) #no idea wtf this does. found online but it works so I'm keeping it
    obj = obj.str.replace(rule1, rule2, regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE) ~~~flags=re.IGN... prevents O(size dictionary constraints) from being written out
data_909['Address_n'] = obj #save it
```

Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem. Cheers

Sample CSV:

```
          Date      Time        Address
2   2015-09-02  13:43:19  241 WARREN ST
11  2015-09-03  10:33:28   29 DEVLIN AV
12  2015-09-03  11:23:11  247 LARREN ST
13  2015-09-03  11:30:55     5 ASTER LA
25  2015-09-04  04:50:52    54 W 5th ST
32  2015-09-04  14:29:47    4 STRUCE RD
```

Comment: Just wanted to share. Let me know if anyone has any other cool solutions!

Comment: Does your samples contains `54 W 5th ST` like values ?

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug what you do mean?